# use mongoose and expressjs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to develop an app using express.js and mongoose, to start an express server
I need to write

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = app.listen(3000, function () {});
```

and to connect to mongo, I need to write sth like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
db.once('open', function (callback) {
  // yay!
});
```

but I don't know how to combine these two codes, so that my server starts answering to request, only if my application has established a correct connection to mongo

Answer (score 2):

create your app

```
var app = express();
```

create your db

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/test');
var db = mongoose.connection;
```

create connection handler with callback

```
var connectDB = function(next){
  //Bootstrap db connection
  mongoose.connect(db, function(err){
    if(err) return next(err);
    next();
  });
};
```

create your server

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
connectDB(function(err){
  var port = 8000;
  if(err) throw new Error('connection error');
  server.listen(port, function(){
    console.log('server listening on port ' + port);
  });
});
```